# SSIS Package Timings

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to obtain some package timings that I can use to perform various analytics on packages.

An example of a high level report could be:

Package Name

Start DateTime

End Date Time

Execution in Secs

Or a bit deeper bringing in Task execution:

Package Name

Task Name

Start DateTime

End Date Time

Execution in Secs

We have packages stored in both MSDB and SSISDB, so any table suggestions would need to cater for both these routes.

Is this possible?

If it is, what tables should I be interrogating within msdb and ssidb?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the [SSIS package logging options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140246.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages deployed to the SSISDB are using the Project Deployment Model. By default, when they are executed they run using the Basic logging option which captures all of the above data. In fact, there are built in reports and external projects for reporting against this data. Generally speaking, you will want to look at that catalog.operations and catalog.operation_messages to discover the above level of timings.

Packages deployed to msdb are using the package deployment model. That doesn't get logging "for free." You will need to go into every package and explicitly enable logging. The events you will be interested in are OnPreExecute and OnPostExecute. That will capture task level detail. The Pacakge itself is automatically going to log it's start and stop time.

Calculating the duration will be done using [datediff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)